# Моргает квадрат в SDL2 C++

Tags: c++, sdl2

При движении и неподвижности квадрат периодически пропадает на мгновение. Это происходит при использовании метода класса graphics.updateWindow(). Скажите пожалуйста как можно избавиться от проблемы.

Graphics.cpp

```
void Graphics::drawRect(SDL_Rect *Rect, uint8_t RGBA[4])
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, RGBA[0], RGBA[1], RGBA[2], RGBA[3]);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(Renderer, Rect);
    SDL_RenderDrawRect(Renderer, Rect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);
}

void Graphics::updateWindow(uint16_t FPS)
{
    SDL_Delay(1000/FPS); // 1000 miliseconds. Result is miliseconds delay
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(Renderer, &background);

}
```

Comment: Зачем вы каждый раз вызываете `SDL_RenderPresent`? Его нужно вызывать один раз после всех вызовов. Вот собственно и ответ.

Comment: Слишком много не относящегося к проблеме кода, нужен [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась. Спасибо, [@こきん](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/206435/%e3%81%93%e3%81%8d%e3%82%93?tab=profile).
Перенёс вызов SDL_RenderPresent из метода drawRect в начало метода updateWindow
Теперь метод graphics.updateWindow()

```
void Graphics::updateWindow(uint16_t FPS)
{
    SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);
    SDL_Delay(1000/FPS); // 1000 miliseconds. Result is miliseconds delay
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(Renderer, &background);

}
```

Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Если перенести его в конец, то экран становится полностью чёрным.